# What's the purpose of callback function if code skips macrotasks?

Tags: javascript, callback

Recently, I've tried to understand callback functions in JavaScript, however, this concept is still far away from my understanding. I have code like this:

```
function exampleFunc(callback) {
    console.log("Starting...");
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Logged after 3 secs.");
    }, 3000);
    callback();
}

function displayMessage() {
    console.log("Log it!");
}
    
exampleFunc(() =>
{
    console.log("Further code.");
});

displayMessage();
```

I've expected that after calling `exampleFunc()`, program will wait 3 seconds, and then call the callback and rest of code. But instead, the sequence of code is:

```
Starting...
Further code.
Log it!
Logged after 3 secs.
```

Why does it happen? I've expected that program will output `"Starting"`, then wait and log `"Logged after 3 secs."`, then go to callback and output `"Further code"`, and in the end, `"Log it!"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a `setTimeout` does not cause further execution of the code in that function to delay. `setTimeout` *schedules* a timeout, then continues executing the rest of the code in the function *immediately*.

You need to call `callback` *inside* the `setTimeout` callback, so that it runs only after the 3 seconds are up.

You also need to put the call of `displayMessage` inside the callback passed to `exampleFunc`.

```js
function exampleFunc(callback) {
  console.log("Starting...");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Logged after 3 secs.");
    callback();
  }, 3000);
}

function displayMessage() {
  console.log("Log it!");
}

exampleFunc(() => {
  console.log("Further code.");
  displayMessage();
});
```

Comment: Why I can't execute ```displayMessage()``` out of ```exampleFunc()``` but I have to put it in ```exampleFunc()```? Why if I do it, then message ```"Log it!"``` gets displayed immediately after ```"Starting..."```?

Comment: Because the call of `exampleFunc` doesn't cause further execution of code to block until the timeout has finished; just like *inside* `exampleFunc`, you have to put `callback()` inside the `setTimeout` for `callback` to wait, you also have to put the `displayMessage` inside the callback passed to `exampleFunc`.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of callback functions if I can just write code further in ```setTimeout()```, instead of calling another function?

Comment: Passing separate callbacks can make the code look more flat and understandable at a glance, especially if the callbacks have good informative names. Unless the script is reasonably big and complicated, feel free to just write everything inside the `setTimeout` - until it starts feeling like a problem to you.

Comment: `while` *is* blocking; it won't continue with the rest of the program or yield control flow to the caller until the `while` is finished. `setTimeout` *schuedules* something for the future; `while` *does* something (whatever's inside the while block) immediately, repeatedly, until the while condition fails.

Comment: Then there is no solution for code to run during while loop? It has to wait despite any circumstances?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want the code inside it to not run immediately, and to let other synchronous code run first, you can wrap the `while` in a `setTimeout`. If you want to add a delay inside a `while`, you can have an async function and `await` a Promise.